# Adding local data_base to apache-superset using docker-composer

Tags: docker, clickhouse, apache-superset

I can't connect a local database to docker-compose running a Superset container.

I'm using Superset to show information of a database that is stored locally. While Superset is running as a container ran by *docker-compose*. Superset can't access the database duo to the container network not being able to access the same IP address and port of [localhost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can connect to your local database by using the docker daemon's network bridge `docker0`.

- use `docker0`'s address (`172.17.0.1`) instead of `localhost`

```bash
~ ip addr show docker0
9: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 1a:2b:3c:4d:5e:6f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Apache Superset's documentation also mentions this [here](https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-using-docker-compose#5-connecting-superset-to-your-local-database-instance).
More information on your underlying question: [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach?rq=1)

Answer (score -1):

For this your Apache Superset should also running on your local system.

Comment: This statement is incorrect. Apache Superset mentions this setup in their [own documentation](https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-using-docker-compose#5-connecting-superset-to-your-local-database-instance).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35028198)

Comment: @user16217248 how is this not an answer? even if an answer is incorrect, it's still an answer.